# random-js array shuffle always returns the same result

Tags: node.js, random-js

I'm using NodeJS 0.12 with random-js to shuffle an array.

it seems that whenever I shuffle the array i get the same result, only when i restart the application the results differ.. only for the first time and then the same until i restart the application again.

this is my code:

```
var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5...];
var Random = require("random-js");
var random = new Random(Random.engines.mt19937().autoSeed());

function generateBalls() {
    var result = random.shuffle(numbers);
    return result;
}
```

any ideas?

More code:

this is the full ballsManagement.js file:

```
var maxNumber = 75;
var minNumber = 1;
var modNumber = 15;
var letters = ['B', 'I', 'N', 'G', 'O'];
var numbers = [];
var numbersToLetters = {};

var Random = require("random-js");
var random = new Random(Random.engines.mt19937().autoSeed());

for (var i = minNumber; i <= maxNumber; i++) {
 numbersToLetters[i] = letters[i % modNumber];
}

for (var i = minNumber; i <= maxNumber; i++) {
 numbers.push(i);
}

function generateBalls() {
 var result = random.shuffle(numbers);
 return result; 
}

module.exports.generateBalls = generateBalls;
module.exports.maxNumber = maxNumber;
module.exports.minNumber = minNumber;
module.exports.modNumber = modNumber;
module.exports.letters = letters;
module.exports.numbers = numbers;
```

then i simply use the generateBalls function in the following code:

```
var ballsManagement = require('../models/ballsManagement');
var balls = ballsManagement.generateBalls();
var balls2 = ballsManagement.generateBalls();
...
```

thanks

Comment: Is this your full example? Can you provide how you invoke generateBalls to get the same results?

Comment: @JuniorCompressor hi, provided the full code. thank you

Comment: Can you include the second call that generates the same results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that the answer is pretty simple :)
the shuffle function modifies the array and returns it, it doesn't duplicate the array and modify the new array.

so in my case i used random twice so both balls and balls2 are pointing to the same array that has been shuffled twice.

so in my case i just create a new array before shuffling it.

```
function generateBalls() {
 var newArr = [];
 for (var i=minNumber;i<=maxNumber;i++) {
    newArr.push(i);
 }
 Random.shuffle(engine,newArr);
 return newArr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pure JS to shuffle any array, for example if you have an array such as

```
var arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
```

you can use this JS code:

```
var arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
function getItemFromDB(){
    var res = ["", "", "", "", ""];
    for(var i=0; i<res.length; i++) {
        var checker = false;
        while(checker == false) {
            var newItem = arr[getRandomInt(0, arr.length)];
            if (res.indexOf(newItem) < 0) {
                res[i] = newItem;
                checker = true;
            }
        }
    }
    alert(res);
}
```

And this for HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type='button' value='Get random array' onclick='getItemFromDB()'/>
</form>
```

It works for me just right.

Comment: thank you for your response. i prefer to know how to fix it using random-js, it's a big project and i use it in a lot of places, so i need to know if i need to replace it project-wide or is there a solution.